# Web API ContainerControlledLifetimeManager - not what expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, which serving http pages and provides REST API using Web API.

I have a "service" class, which supposed to be a singleton and to be used both in ASP.NET MVC and Web API parts.

For dependency injection, I using Unity. I installed from NuGet Unity, Unity.AspNet.Mvc and Unity.AspNet.WebApi packages.

I registering my service as singleton:

```
container.RegisterType<IService, ServiceImp>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

What I see is that different instances of "ServiceImp" created for ASP.NET MVC and for Web API. The constructor called twice. It looks like there are two separate containers there...

All contents of UnityConfig.cs, UnityMvcActivator.cs and UnityWebApiActivator.cs remained unchanged as initial template, except the place where I register my services.

Any idea how to solve this issue? What I doing wrong?

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
namespace Management.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IService, ServiceImp>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
    }
}
```

**UnityMvcActivator.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Management.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Management.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace Management.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**UnityWebApiActivator.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Management.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Management.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace Management.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with WebApi when it is hosted in ASP.NET</summary>
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 9.9.17**

After some digging, I see that Application_Start called twice - first time when any http page requested and second time when REST API called. As a result, everything initialized twice, including Unity. Now I need to find out why this happens...

Comment: Can you post your UnityConfig.cs, UnityMvcActivator.cs and UnityWebApiActivator.cs?

Comment: @ovation22: done